# JSON.parse() returns wrong values for integers

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

[EDIT] I was modyfing the data later and it was reflected in the object when expanding it, I will accept my answer when I can.[/EDIT]

I've got a simple JSON string that needs parsing:

```
{"Points": [{"x": 0,"y": 33},{"x": 2200,"y": 28},{"x": 4400,"y": 23},{"x": 6600,"y": 20},{"x": 8800,"y": 19},{"x": 11000,"y": 18},{"x": 13200,"y": 17},{"x": 15400,"y": 15},{"x": 17600,"y": 13},{"x": 19800,"y": 12}]}
```

The string is generated by C++ code for graph drawing purposes. When I paste it into a json formatter it parses fine, giving proper values. The problem I'm facing are wierd Y values, for example the first object in array "Points" has y value of 20 - and there are no 20's anywhere in the string.

See attached picture, it explains everything. The code before what's on the picture is as follows:

```
RequestJSONParse: function(Data)
{
    var Request = Data.split("|");
    var RequestType = Request[0];
    var RequestParams = Request[1];
    var RequestData = undefined;

    if (typeof Request[2] != "undefined" && Request[2] != "")
    {                       
        console.log("---");
        console.log(Request[2]);
        console.log("---");

        RequestData = JSON.parse(Request[2]);

        console.log("---");
        console.log(RequestData);
        console.log("---");
    }
```

My question is - are the some special characters or a special way JSON.parse parses specifically x,y values? Or is this an encoding issue or something I can't even think of? I've been on this project for 2 years and didn't ever encounter anything like this and most of our UI is made by parsing JSON data.

[Image explaining the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGmYS.jpg)

Comment: Here's a 20: `{"x": 6600,"y": 20}`

Comment: http://jsbin.com/paganawado/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Note also the blue `i` next to your `RequestData` log - are you manipulating the data in this - it appears that it was perhaps modified after you logged it, and you're viewing the modified data after you expanded it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe This was the key, I was modifying the data later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JamesThorpe Was on point, I was modifying the object later and my changes were reflected in the object when it was expanded. The blue i symbol was the missing link for me.

Comment: you accepted your own answer rather than asked the contributor to post the comment as answer?

Answer (score 2):

Check here your do like this

```
var json = "{\"Points\": [{\"x\": 0,\"y\": 33},{\"x\": 2200,\"y\": 28},{\"x\": 4400,\"y\": 23},{\"x\": 6600,\"y\": 20},{\"x\": 8800,\"y\": 19},{\"x\": 11000,\"y\": 18},{\"x\": 13200,\"y\": 17},{\"x\": 15400,\"y\": 15},{\"x\": 17600,\"y\": 13},{\"x\": 19800,\"y\": 12}]}";
var Request = json.split("|");
var data = JSON.parse(Request[0]);
console.log(data);
```

U can use above code if u r getting string in this way....